# 14.04 server: udev incorrect group ownership

Tags: 14.04, permissions, udev

Using this rule:

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{product}=="CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller", SYMLINK+="usb_zwave", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"`

Gets me this link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           7 Nov 22 22:59 usb_zwave -> ttyUSB0s
```

The group ownership of the link does not reflect the GROUP argument in the rule. I can correctly access the link as root, but not as another user.

Any thoughts how to resolve? Thanks

Update: requested info

```
root@home:/dev# sudo ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0*
crw-rw-rw-  1 root dialout      188, 0 Nov 27 20:36 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and  add output of `sudo ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0*` ?

Comment: Just to make sure:  you do reload yr rule with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` after each change and and name it with  for instance "99_" as a name prefix so it is taken into account last in your chain of existing rules... Are you all clear on that ?  Also look up http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124540/writing-raw-images-safely-to-usb-sticks. I think your answer lies right there, but if you need more assistance please add relevant info to your question by editing it.

Comment: .... and check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev.

Comment: root@home:/dev# sudo ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 27 20:36 /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: It turned out to be complete ignorance on the inner workings of udev on my part and the inability to deal with symlinks of the application to raised the issue. Now it's clear that udev behaviour is normal: links are ALWAYS created as owned by root and fully writable. Any access restrictions need to be set on the target of the link, which is what the group argument in udev is for. Then the java application needed to be made "symlink aware" by adding -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=/dev/symlinkname to the JAVA_ARGS_DEFAULT section of the startup script.

Comment: @coyote , i come back here by chance , when you want to reply someone add `@` to be notified, like i put you name in this comment.

Comment: @coyote , nice that you got it, could you write that as an answer. see http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer , then you can accept it after 2 days